# How to process two long lines with constant memory?

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation

Input file consists of two lines, each of which holds many numbers

```
1 2 3 4... 
5 6 7 8...
```

I want to process each line's data, like this:

```
doSomething :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
doSomething [] y = 0 -- stop execution. I'm concerted in memory behavior only.
doSomething (x:xs) y = doSomething xs y
main = do
    inputdata <- getContents
    let (x:xs) = lines inputdata
        firstLine = map (read ::String->Int) $ words $ x
        secondLine = map (read ::String->Int) $ words $ head xs
    print $ doSomething firstLine secondLine
```

When I run this program, heap profiling shows like this:
[image]

If I don't use secondLine (`xs`) then this program runs with constant memory.
Each entry of list `firstLine` is processed then discarded by GC.
[image]

1. Why the consumed memory is so large? 
   I see the amount of allocated memory is ~100MB, but actual input data size is 5MB.
2. Does `head xs` force reading entire first line into memory,
   even `secondLine` is not used at all? And is this the main cause
   of memory increase of heap profiling graph?
3. How can I process two lines with constant memory, like latter execution graph?
4. If the answer to 3) depends on processing order, how can I process second line first, and then first line?

Comment: Can each line be processed completely independently, or do they need to be processed "in lockstep"?

Comment: My original intention is to process first line after processing second line completely. I cannot imagine a way to do in lockstep.

Comment: Note that Haskell's `String` is *very* memory-consuming because each character takes (at least) 4 bytes. So if you have a 5MB text file, reading all of it into memory will use like 20+MB of RAM. You are then creating lists of `Int` of the same length, which should at least double the memory. And the call to `doSomething` if it isn't lazy will again double that, easily reaching like 80+MB. Using a `ByteString` can probably significantly reduce this (and makes reads and writes much more efficient).

Comment: @cwyang Your comment conflicts with the code above. If `doSomething` forces `y`(`secondLine`) to be evaluated, this will cause `lines` to go ahead until a newline is found, while remembering what precedes it since it will be put into `firstLine`. So: are you actually accessing the second line before the first, as your comment implies?

Comment: @Bakruriu I see. However I expect heap grows by ~20MB since above code does lazy `getContents`. I cannot find out why over 100MB is consumed. `map . words` should not be done on second line and first line's `map. words` should be disposed by GC. :-(

Comment: @chi You're right. I expect only relatively small memory required by reading first line is consumed. But memory was consumed more than I expected. So I want to know there is a kind of thunk leak or not. I asked Q1) and Q2) in light of it.

Comment: Counting the overhead from the list nodes and internal meta-data, on 64-bit architectures `String` takes 24 bytes per character.  If your input was essentially ASCII, then that's a 24 fold increase in space usage.  `String` is extremely space inefficient (and just generally inefficient).  Hence `Text` and `ByteString`.

Comment: As the answer to Q3 in practice, you should look into a streaming IO library.  Some of the most popular libraries right now are [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), [conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), and [io-streams](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/io-streams).  Any of these will be faster, less fragile, and more featureful (e.g. supporting compressed IO) than trying to use `getContents`.

Comment: When compiled with `-O2` your program in fact runs with constant memory. If the `firstLine` isn't used the program also runs with constant memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1) Why the consumed memory is so large? I see the amount of allocated memory is ~100MB, but actual input data size is 5MB.

`String` in Haskell is a type alias for `[Char]`, so along the actual bytes, the compiler also has to keep a constructor, a pointer to the boxed character and a pointer to the next constructor for every character in the memory, results >10 times of memory usage than a C-style string. Even worse the text is stored multiple times in memory.

> Q3) How can I process two lines with constant memory, like latter execution graph?
>   Q4) If the answer to Q3) depends on processing order, how can I process second line first, and then first line?

No you can't process the second line first since the `lines` function have to evaluate every byte in the first line to hit the '\n' newline character.

> Q2) Does head xs force reading entire first line into memory, even secondLine is not used at all? And is this the main cause of memory increase of heap profiling graph?

It's not the `head` that prevents the first line from being GCed. The space leak still occurs if you adjust the type signature of `doSomething` and pass `xs` directly to it. The point is the (not optimizing) compiler won't know that `secondLine` isn't used before `doSomething` finally hits the first pattern, so the program keeps a reference to `xs` . BTW if compiled with -O2 your program runs with constant memory.

What caused the space leak of your program is mainly this line:

```
let (x:xs) = lines inputdata
```

When either `x` or `xs` is discarded, this let clause will be in-lined in the dumped Core. Only when both of them are referenced later the Core behaves strangely: it constructs a tuple, destruct it by pattern matching, then construct the two part into a tuple again, therefore by keeping a reference to `secondLine` the program in fact keeps a reference to a tuple `(x,  xs)` so the first line will never be GCed.

Core with `secondLine` commented out:

```
Rec {
doSomething_rjH
doSomething_rjH =
  \ ds_d1lv y_alG ->
    case ds_d1lv of _ {
      [] -> I# 0;
      : x_alH xs_alI -> doSomething_rjH xs_alI y_alG
    }
end Rec }

main
main =
  >>=
    $fMonadIO
    getContents
    (\ inputdata_app ->
       print
         $fShowInt
         (doSomething_rjH
            (map
               (read $fReadInt)
               (words
                  (case lines inputdata_app of _ {
                     [] -> case irrefutPatError "a.hs:6:9-32|(x : xs)"# of wild1_00 { };
                     : x_auf xs_aug -> x_auf
                   })))
            ([])))

main
main = runMainIO main
```

Core with space leak:

```
Rec {
doSomething_rjH
doSomething_rjH =
  \ ds_d1ol y_alG ->
    case ds_d1ol of _ {
      [] -> I# 0;
      : x_alH xs_alI -> doSomething_rjH xs_alI y_alG
    }
end Rec }

main
main =
  >>=
    $fMonadIO
    getContents
    (\ inputdata_app ->
       -- *** Construct ***
       let {
         ds_d1op
         ds_d1op =
           case lines inputdata_app of _ {
             [] -> irrefutPatError "a.hs:6:9-30|x : xs"#;
             : x_awM xs_awN -> (x_awM, xs_awN)
           } } in
       -- *** Destruct ***
       let {
         xs_awN
         xs_awN = case ds_d1op of _ { (x_awM, xs1_XwZ) -> xs1_XwZ } } in
       let {
         x_awM
         x_awM = case ds_d1op of _ { (x1_XwZ, xs1_XwU) -> x1_XwZ } } in
       -- *** Construct ***
       let {
         ds1_d1oq
         ds1_d1oq = (x_awM, xs_awN) } in
       print
         $fShowInt
         -- *** Destruct ***
         (doSomething_rjH
            (map
               (read $fReadInt)
               (words (case ds1_d1oq of _ { (x1_Xx1, xs1_Xx3) -> x1_Xx1 })))
            (map
               (read $fReadInt)
               (words
                  (head (case ds1_d1oq of _ { (x1_Xx1, xs1_Xx3) -> xs1_Xx3 }))))))

main
main = runMainIO main
```

Replace the `let` clause by a `case .. of` clause will fix the space leak:

```
doSomething :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
doSomething [] _ = 0 -- stop execution. I'm concerted in memory behavior only.
doSomething (_:xs) y = doSomething xs y

main :: IO ()
main = do
  inputdata <- getContents
  case lines inputdata of
    x:xs -> do
      let
        firstLine = map (read ::String->Int) $ words x
        secondLine = map (read ::String->Int) $ words $ head xs
      print $ doSomething firstLine secondLine
```

The dumped Core. The "construct then destruct" pattern didn't happen this time:

```
Rec {
doSomething_rjG
doSomething_rjG =
  \ ds_d1o6 ds1_d1o7 ->
    case ds_d1o6 of _ {
      [] -> I# 0;
      : ds2_d1o8 xs_alG -> doSomething_rjG xs_alG ds1_d1o7
    }
end Rec }

main
main =
  >>=
    $fMonadIO
    getContents
    (\ inputdata_apn ->
       case lines inputdata_apn of _ {
         [] -> patError "a.hs:(8,3)-(13,46)|case"#;
         : x_asI xs_asJ ->
           print
             $fShowInt
             (doSomething_rjG
                (map (read $fReadInt) (words x_asI))
                (map (read $fReadInt) (words (head xs_asJ))))
       })

main
main = runMainIO main
```

Comment: Thanks :-) I've got it but this one: `It's not the head that prevents the first line from being GCed. The point is the (not optimizing) compiler won't know that secondLine isn't used before doSomething finally hits the first pattern, so the program keeps a reference to xs .` Can GC discard processed one while traversing `x` even if it hold a reference to `xs`? Because traversing `x` occurs prior than hitting `xs`. GC cannot dispose `x` if it holds another reference of `x`. Also GC cannot dispose 'x' if traversing 'xs' occurs first. But not in this case.

Comment: @cwyang Yes, your argument makes total sense and should be the default behavior and is the default behavior of `ghc -O2` (though I have no way to confirm but the memory usage graph, because Core dumped by `ghc -O2` is barely readable) But plain `ghc -O0` is ... just not so eagerly fixing this sort of space leak I guess. I made a minor adjustment to your program and now it runs in constant memory, you can see how minor the change is whilst it does the trick.